# copying dependencies to libs folder in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build, jar

I am trying to copy all the dependencies to libs folder, but it isn't working with the copyDependency task. I've tried few tweaks with the task, however it won't copy. Below is my build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url = uri('https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/')
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:2.0.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:2.0.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.0.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.2'
    compile 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.197'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.290'
    compile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4'
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.1'
    compile 'com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot-starter:1.15'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.0.2.RELEASE'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test:4.0.1.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.loyalty.finance'
description = 'Spring Boot and batch integrated project for fin-issuance-processor'
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from(components.java)
        }
    }
}
task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.runtime
    into 'libs'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Comment: Just tried your build file, and it is working fine for me. Note however, that unless you are on a very old version of Gradle, you should be using `type: Sync` and `from configuration.runtimeClasspath` and `into file('libs')` to make it more robust.

Comment: Unless by "all dependencies" you mean everything including test-only dependencies. In that case, use `from configurations.testRuntimeClasspath`.

Comment: @BjørnVester Sorry I didn't mention. I want it in the libs folder of build package that is created after packaging the code.

Comment: This is working for me
task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.runtime
    into "${rootProject.buildDir}/libs"
}